# Where to change "installed" for Auto Layout constraint?

Tags: ios, ios8, screen-rotation, autolayout

When using Auto Layout in a storyboard there's an option to keep a constraint installed or not with an "Installed" checkbox. Disabling it will cause it to behave as if you didn't add that constraint - it will have no effect. You can configure the installed state for different size classes in Interface Builder, and you can change this value programmatically by setting its `active` property to `true` or `false`.

In my app I want to have a constraint installed only while the device is in portrait - it should be "uninstalled" when rotating to landscape. This can be accomplished for iPhones by unchecking installed for Any Width Compact Height. (Although this doesn't seem to work quite right because it breaks this constraint due to conflicting constraints when rotating to landscape when it shouldn't even be installed, but regardless the UI always appears as expected.) But there is no way to uninstall the constraint for the iPad in landscape in Interface Builder (it's Regular Width Regular Height in both orientations).

**Where is the proper place to enable/disable `active` for `NSLayoutConstraint`s when rotating the device?** In what rotation method will changing that status result in the desired behavior - only be installed for portrait? If that method isn't called upon app launch, in what other method should it be placed in addition to a rotation method?

I've tried placing the following code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillTransitionToSize` but this results in some unexpected behavior when running on iPad:

- Launching the app in landscape causes the constraint to be active despite the fact active was set to false, it breaks the constraint, and the UI doesn't appear as expected
- Launching the app in portrait sets active to true (it was already installed in IB) so it works as expected
- Launching the app in portrait and rotating the device to landscape works as expected - constraint is set to inactive, it doesn't break the constraint, UI appears as expected
- Launching the app in portrait, rotating to landscape, and back to portrait causes the UI to appear correct but it breaks this constraint that is set to active

If I uninstall the constraint in Interface Builder then run the above scenarios I get essentially the opposite behavior.

```
if size.width > size.height {
    self.myConstraint.active = false
} else {
    self.myConstraint.active = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to answer but here is my 2 cents when I faced a similar problem to resolve the problem of Autolayout's inability to detect Compact Width/Compact Height for iPhone with iOS 7 . There is no `activated` property in iOS 7, so I had to add/remove them.

I created two methods to add and remove constraints, and these constraints are already set on IB and I reference them with IBOutlet properties. So, since I remove them, unlike other IB objects, I should set them to `strong`, not `weak`. Otherwise, once I removed them they will be destroyed and I won't be able to reference them once more to re-add them.

Here is my constraint remover method:

```
-(void)removeiOS7andiPhone4inLandscapeToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

    if( !UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation )&&(NSFoundationVersionNumber<=NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)&&( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )){
         // if iPhone with iOS 7 on portrait remove Constraints here

    }
}
```

and here is the constraint adder method:

```
-(void)addiOS7andiPhone4inLandscapeToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation )&&(NSFoundationVersionNumber<=NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)&&( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )){
       // if iPhone with iOS 7 on landscape add Constraints here

    }

}
```

As for where to call these methods, as you tried, call both of them  in `viewWillAppear`( no need to call in `viewWillDisappear`) and `viewWillTransitionToSize` ( in my case this is `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, since `viewWillTransitionToSize` is only available after iOS 8) . Calling them subsequently makes sense, after all only one of them will be run due to checking their portrait/landscape orientation with `if`, before making the necessary changes.

and here is my `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method definition:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // this will be run only if orientation is on Portrait
    [self addiOS7andiPhone4inLandscapeToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

    // this will be run only if orientation is on Landscape
    [self removeiOS7andiPhone4inLandscapeToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

and make a similar call in `viewWillAppear`.

**NOTICE**: make sure you are doing the exact opposite in these methods, and you don't necessarily add constraints only in addConstraintMethod and remove only in removeConstraintMethod. In my case, I both add and remove constraints in each of them, so the naming of the methods don't reflect to true role of them exactly, but as long as you are doing the exact opposites you are good to go .

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would have used these methods, but the downside with them is that they only inform controller when there is a change.

```
/* 
 This method is called when the view controller's view's size is changed by its parent (i.e. for the root view controller when its window rotates or is resized). 

 If you override this method, you should either call super to propagate the change to children or manually forward the change to children.
 */
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

/* 
 This method is called when the view controller's trait collection is changed by its parent.

 If you override this method, you should either call super to propagate the change to children or manually forward the change to children.
 */
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

To do customisation on constraints, initially and on orientation change, I prefer,

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```